# Java code to calculate number of elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, file, file-io, int

I have code which creates an ArrayList from the file "line.txt". Can you suggest some ways to get the number of elements in that ArrayList? For example: If the file has elements such as (43,6,32) then, the output should be given as 3(number of elements).

```
public class scan {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("line.txt"))) {
      for (String part : line.split("\\s+")) {
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(part);
        numbers.add(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `numbers.size()`?

Comment: The first thing that you should do is check the API of the class you are interested in. Here is the one for ArrayList: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Maybe numbers.size() or a method that increments an integer while you search for the number.next()=null;. In any case, search in the java API of arraylist, there's a method to know the size of the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList<> has it's own API in docs.oracle:

docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

In your case:

```
public class scan {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("line.txt"))) {
  for (String part : line.split("\\s+")) {
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(part);
    numbers.add(i);
  }
}
int answer = number.size();
System.out.println("The number of elements is: " + answer);
}
}
```

If you want another way of doing it(but it's a bit idiotic if you only want to know the number of elements). Is transforming it to an array and count the number of elements of the array by .length, but as I said, it's a bit... long.